# .Net client received 401 Unauthorized from SignalRHub using Azure AD

Tags: c#, signalr, .net-6.0, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm trying to do a test in which I use a .Net client to connect to a SignalR Hub using Azure AD for an authentication.

I have a token from the client and post within the connect request but got 401 unauthorized.

I'm not sure what goes wrong, so I'll post everything here (SignalR Hub and .Net client)

All the document I look at are:

- https://dev.to/425show/secure-net-5-signalr-solutions-with-azure-ad-36ec
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-howto-authorize-application

**1. SignalR Hub**

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

using SignalRChat.Hubs;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var configuration = builder.Configuration;

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddMvcCore();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services
    .AddSignalR()
    .AddAzureSignalR("Endpoint=https://my-signalr-dev.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=eweqwewqewqewqewqewqewqe;Version=1.0;");

builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(configuration);

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHub<ChatHubAuthorize>("/chat");
});

app.Run();
```

ChatHubAuthorize.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

using SignalRChat.Services;

using System.Security.Claims;

namespace SignalRChat.Hubs
{
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
    public class ChatHubAuthorize : Hub
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ChatHub> _logger;

        public IConnectionService _connectionService { get; set; }

        public ChatHubAuthorize(ILogger<ChatHub> logger, IConnectionService service)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _connectionService = service;
        }

        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            var username = GetEmailFromTokenClaims(this.Context);
            _logger.LogInformation($"{username} connected");

            _connectionService.AddNew(Context.ConnectionId);
            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)
        {
            var username = GetEmailFromTokenClaims(this.Context);
            _logger.LogInformation($"{username} disconnected");

            _connectionService.RemoveConnection(Context.ConnectionId);
            return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }

        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.Others.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }

        private string GetEmailFromTokenClaims(HubCallerContext context)
        {
            return context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type.Equals(ClaimTypes.Email, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Value;
        }
    }
}
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "mytesting.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "a********b",
    "ClientId": "c********d"
  }
}
```

**2. .Net Client**

Program.cs

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using SignalRChatClient;

var _accessToken = string.Empty;
var _redirectUri = "http://localhost";
var _connection = "https://localhost:7135/chat";
var _clientId = "c*******d";

var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(_clientId)
                .WithRedirectUri(_redirectUri)
                .WithAuthority(AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdMultipleOrgs)
                .Build();

AuthenticationResult result;
var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
var scopes = new string[] { };

try
{
    result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes,
        accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();
}
catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
{
    result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
}

var hubClient = new HubClientAuthorize(_connection, result);
await hubClient.Connect();

var msg = Console.ReadLine();
while (msg != "exit")
{
    await hubClient.SendMessage(msg);
    msg = Console.ReadLine();
}

await hubClient.Disconnect();
```

HubClientAuthorize.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

namespace SignalRChatClient
{
    public class HubClientAuthorize
    {
        private HubConnection _hubConnection;
        private string _user;

        public HubClientAuthorize(string connection,AuthenticationResult authenticationResult)
        {
            _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl(connection, option =>
                {
                    option.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(authenticationResult.AccessToken);
                })
                //.WithAutomaticReconnect()
                .Build();
            _hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage",
                (user, message) =>
                {
                    Print(user, message);
                });
            _user = authenticationResult.Account.Username;
        }

        private void Print(string user, string message)
        {
            if (user != _user)
            {
                var str = $"{user}: {message}";
                Console.WriteLine(str);
            }
        }

        public async Task Connect()
        {
            await _hubConnection.StartAsync();//error this line 401 Unauthorized
        }

        public async Task Disconnect()
        {
            await _hubConnection.StopAsync();
            await _hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
        }

        public async Task SendMessage(string message)
        {
            await _hubConnection.InvokeAsync("SendMessage", _user, message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**

- Both SignalRHub and client are .Net 6
- I try to download the document in the link#1 but got the same thing 401 unauthorized
- For security, I have to replace the real values with **** characters
- The error happens in client (the line which calls `await _hubConnection.StartAsync();`)
- In the client, the line `result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();` let the browser redirect to a microsoft link then I enter my credentials and it says ok as below

[image]

Thanks